# No response from HTTP request

Tags: java, android

i have written an android app which post data to my database. The app should access an webservice which post the data to the database. the webservice works fine. ive testet it with my browser, he is already on the server. now i want my app to execute the webservice. but that doesnt work. My debugger doesnt work too so im not able to debug. here is my code to for accessing the webservice. any ideas??

```
public class PostBlog extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String BlogURL;

public PostBlog(String insertBlogURL) {
    BlogURL = insertBlogURL;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    postBlogData(BlogURL);
    return null;
}

public void postBlogData(String url) {

    String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "1980"));

    //http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        //(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.question)
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


}
```

}

The Class is called from my main Activity by

```
new PostBlog(insertBlogURL).execute("");
```

Is there another easier way to execute my ".jsp?asdd=sdsd" file on the server?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Just add logs if you're not able to debug app. And tell us what logs say.

Comment: how to add logs and where ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html After every line that you're not sure what result it produces. And if you're studying android you'd better get along with debugger. Posting question on stackoverflow won't help if you can't understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing :

`new PostBlog(insertBlogURL).execute("");`

Change your constructor and retrieve the url from the `doInBackground` method, by doing `params[0]`

Then initiate the download like this

```
PostBlog blogPoster = new PostBlog();
try {
    blogPoster.execute(insertBlogURL);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {} catch (ExecutionException e) {}
```

I should say this is a modified snippet of code from my own project, so it might not work exactly the way you expect.

Comment: Can you write how the changed constructor should look like ? Why do you add 2 Exceptions to 1 try? Compiler shows error 4 this.Thanks.

Comment: @theAlgorithmGod delete your constructor alltogether, you don't need it. In you doInBackground, instead of passing `BlogURL` to your `postBlogData` method, pass `params[0]`

Comment: @theAlgorithmGod I catch two errors so as to be precise, you could of course just catch a general `Exception` but then you can't tell which error occured exactly, I cannot help you with your compiler errors much without knowing them, though I do recommend working on them yourself, since they are probably syntax issues